After update to .NET 9: Services for database providers 'SqlServer', 'InMemory' have been registered in the service provider
Upgraded from .NET 8 to 9 and I now get an error in my integration tests:

System.InvalidOperationException
Services for database providers 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer', 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory' have been registered in the service provider.
Only a single database provider can be registered in a service provider. If possible, ensure that Entity Framework is managing its service provider by removing the call to 'UseInternalServiceProvider'.
Otherwise, consider conditionally registering the database provider, or maintaining one service provider per database provider.

My Startup.cs:
var migrationsAssembly = typeof(MyDbContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

services
    .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(
            this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WuitCMDBDefaultConnection"),
            sql =>
            {
                sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly);
            });
    });

My Custom Web App Factory
public class MyCustomWAF<TStartup> :
    WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
    where TStartup : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
        
            services.RemoveAll<DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>>();

            services
            .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options
                    .UseInMemoryDatabase("MyDBInMemory");
                options.ConfigureWarnings(x => x.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.TransactionIgnoredWarning));
            });
        });
    }
}

I am following docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-9.0#customize-webapplicationfactory
Moving my code to OnConfiguring fixed the issue, however it breaks dotnet ef tools when doing migrations. I get a new error that IConfiguration cannot be injected!
// Breaks dotnet-ef migrations!!!
protected override void OnConfiguring(
    DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        var migrationsAssembly = this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("WuitCMDBDefaultConnection"), sql =>
        {
            sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly);
        });
    }
}

With the above code I found that OnConfiguring runs AFTER my Custom WAF code, this optionsBuilder.IsConfigured works. VS calling UseSqlServer in my Startup seems to run BEFORE my Custom WAF. How can I remove all the UseSqlServer services??

This is apparently a known issue with EF Core 9, and has visibility with the EF Core team now.
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/35126
